# How to use const value inside the string in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm writing React JS code for webpage.

The tutorial says the const value can be used inside the string with ${ } expression.

However, when I try it in my IDLE, it just recognize them as same string not const value.

What should I do to call saved const value inside the string

This is what it is supposed to be:
[image: Expected result]

This is what I get instead:

[image: Actual result I got instead]

```
async function getHeadlines(search) {
    const url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=au&apiKey={API_KEY}&q=${search}';
    let res = await fetch(url);
    let data = await res.json();
    let articles = data.articles;
    return articles.map((article) => ({
        title: article.title,
        url: article.url,
    }));
}
```

Comment: Use backticks `\``, not single quotes. This is the thing to the left of the number 1 key on most keyboards, it shares the key with the "~"

Comment: You need to replace ' by `

Comment: Also you're missing a `$` in one of them.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use backtick. Please go throught [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to understand how backtick works.

```
const url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=au&apiKey=${API_KEY}&q=${search}`;
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand your question, you have to use template strings (check [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for more) for this URL:

const url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=au&apiKey={API_KEY}&q=${search}`;

Now you can add `API_KEY` and `search` into a string.

Comment: template *literal*

Answer (score 1):

Like everyone else said, you need to use backticks for [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

It looks like you are confusing non-template literal strings with template literals and their syntax (you forgot a `$` in one of the literal block declarations). Let's have a little review, shall we?

Non-template literal strings look like this:

```
"This is a string with double quotes. It does not parse literals (${})";

'This is a string with single quotes. It does not parse literals (${})';
```

They use either single quotes (`'`) or double quotes (`"`).

Template literals are a special type of string, they allow insertion of variables and/or other data without having to use string concatenation (`"This string " + "just got concatenated"`). To do so, you have to wrap your code you want outputted in a `${}` block, like this:

```
const textToInsert = "Hello, world!";

`This is a template literal. It is a string that allows easier concatenation without using the "+" operator. This parses literals, see? "${textToInsert}"`
```

Since the code is "executed", you can also use ternary operators:

```
`A random number I am thinking of is ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) >= 5 ? "greater than or equal to five" : "less than five"}`
```

Template literals are also useful if you use double quotes or single quotes in your string. If you use a single quote to declare a string that uses single quotes, you would have to escape them:

```
'It\'s a wonderful life'
```

The same applies to double quote strings using double quotes:

```
"\"I have no special talent. I am only passionately curious\" - Albert Einstein"
```

But, if you use template literals, you can use both single and double quotes without escaping them (note that you will have to escape backticks (`` ` ``)):

```
`
It's a wonderful life.

"I have no special talent. I am only passionately curious" - Albert Einstein
`
```

Oh, I forgot to mention - *template literals support newlines*!!!

The conclusion? Template literals are powerful! You just have to know how to use them :)

So, what would your fixed template literal look like?

It would look like this:

```
`https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=au&apiKey=${API_KEY}&q=${search}`;
```